# Программная архитектура последовательности логических вентилей

Tags: c#, unity3d, логика, булева-алгебра

Обучающее приложение по логическим операциям: игрок может собирать цепи (схемы) из логических вентилей. Я хочу, чтобы, собрав какую-то цепь, он мог объединить ее в один.

Например, собираем схему из двух вентилей (AND и NOT) и объединяем в вентиль NAND:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом каждый вентиль может иметь один или несколько входов (вводов) и один или несколько выходов (выводов).

Я не могу придумать, **как мне прописать такой класс вентиля**.
Вот мои идеи:

1. Создать делегат: 'delegate List GateFunction(List)'
2. Класс вентиля содержит поле 'GateFunction func', которое определяет функцию, по которой вводы (inputs) преобразуются в выводы (outputs).
3. Класс вентиля содержит массив 'List _inputs', который содержит ссылки на выводы предыдущих вентилей, которые подсоединяются проводами к вводам данного вентиля.

**Очень важно,** что один вентиль может иметь НЕСКОЛЬКО выводов, и разные выводы одного вентиля могут потом идти к разным вентилям.

Мне нужна такая архитектура, чтобы каждый экземпляр класса хранил в себе КОНКРЕТНУЮ функцию func, оперирующую базовыми функциями.

***ПРИ ЭТОМ ГЛАВНОЕ***, что в рантайме пользователь будет строить и сохранять свои, новые, кастомные вентили, состоящие из ранее созданных (или базовых: and/or/not).

Буду благодарен как общим советам так и коду. Возможно, я упускаю какой-то удобный очевидный паттерн...

> Идея и скриншоты взяты из видео Sebastian Lague (https://youtu.be/QZwneRb-zqA). В нем отлично показано, что мне нужно с 4 по 5 минуту.

---

---

---

***UPD: Пример-пояснение***. Игрок на поле может собрать из имеющихся блоков схемы слева, нажать на кнопочку "Create" и получить соответствующие блоки справа. При этом, как видно, все функции слева открыты, то есть могут быть подсоединены к первоначальным контактам (на 1-м скриншоте слева на экране). Эти контакты кнопкой мыши включаются и выключаются. То есть эти контакты НЕ входят в сам вентиль. Таким образом, нужна возможность указать готовому, собранному вентилю, к каким контактам присоединяются его инпуты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

***UPD2:*** А по кнопке "Create" вентиль должен сохраняться в менюшку, чтобы потом его оттуда можно было взять и использовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Паттерн называется "композит", позволяет как раз собирать элементы из набора других элементов или схемы из "подсхем" в вашем случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не Unity-программист, но, с учётом того что блоки должны поддерживать возможность изменения из GUI, на обычном C# это можно реализовать как-то так.

**Генераторы сигнала:**

```
// генератор сигналов (ничего не принимает на вход)
public interface ISignalGenerator
{
    public bool GetOutput();
}
```

```
// генератор True-сигналов
// реализует синглтон, так как более чем в одном таком генераторе смысла нет, он может даже не быть отдельным блоком в GUI
public sealed class TrueGenerator : ISignalGenerator
{
    private static TrueGenerator? s_instance;

    public static TrueGenerator Instance => s_instance ??= new();

    private TrueGenerator() { }

    public bool GetOutput() => true;
}
```

```
// генератор False-сигналов
// реализует синглтон, так как более чем в одном таком генераторе смысла нет, он может даже не быть отдельным блоком в GUI
public sealed class FalseGenerator : ISignalGenerator
{
    private static FalseGenerator? s_instance;

    public static FalseGenerator Instance => s_instance ??= new();

    private FalseGenerator() { }

    public bool GetOutput() => false;
}
```

**Вентиль:**

```
// вентиль (генерирует сигнал на основе входных сигналов)
public interface ILogicGate : ISignalGenerator
{
    // список генераторов для каждого из входов
    public IReadOnlyList<ISignalGenerator> InputGenerators { get; }

    // присоединить вход под номером inputIndex к генератору inputGenerator
    public void ConnectInputWithOutput(int inputIndex, ISignalGenerator inputGenerator);

    // отсоединить вход под номером inputIndex от генератора (по-сути, это тоже самое что и присоединить к False-генератору) 
    public void DisconnectInputGenerator(int inputIndex);
}
```

**Вентили с множеством входом:**

```
public abstract class MultiInputGate : ILogicGate
{
    private readonly ISignalGenerator[] _inputGenerators;

    public IReadOnlyList<ISignalGenerator> InputGenerators { get; }

    public MultiInputGate(int inputsCount)
    {
        if (inputsCount <= 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputsCount));

        _inputGenerators = new ISignalGenerator[inputsCount];
        InputGenerators  = new ReadOnlyCollection<ISignalGenerator>(_inputGenerators);

        // подсоединяем все входы к False-генератору
        for (int i = 0; i < inputsCount; i++)
            _inputGenerators[i] = FalseGenerator.Instance;
    }

    public void DisconnectInputGenerator(int inputIndex)
    {
        if (inputIndex < 0 || inputIndex >= InputGenerators.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        ConnectInputWithOutput(inputIndex, FalseGenerator.Instance);
    }

    public virtual void ConnectInputWithOutput(int inputIndex, ISignalGenerator inputGenerator)
    {
        if (inputIndex < 0 || inputIndex >= InputGenerators.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        _inputGenerators[inputIndex] = inputGenerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputGenerator));
    }

    public abstract bool GetOutput();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var inputs = string.Join(", ", InputGenerators.Select(generator => Convert.ToInt32(generator.GetOutput())));
        var output = Convert.ToInt32(GetOutput());

        return $"({inputs}) ---{GetType().Name}--> {output}";
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class AndGate : MultiInputGate
{
    public AndGate() : base(2) { }

    public override bool GetOutput() => InputGenerators[0].GetOutput() & InputGenerators[1].GetOutput();
}
```

**Вентили с 1-м входом:**

Класс `SingleInputGate` создан для удобного взаимодействия (например, позволяет писать `gate.InputGenerator` вместо `gate.InputGenerators[0]`).

```
public abstract class SingleInputGate : ILogicGate
{
    private readonly ISignalGenerator[] _inputGenerators;

    public ISignalGenerator InputGenerator
    {
        get => _inputGenerators[0];
        private set => _inputGenerators[0] = value;
    }
    IReadOnlyList<ISignalGenerator> ILogicGate.InputGenerators => _inputGenerators;

    public SingleInputGate()
    {
        _inputGenerators = new ISignalGenerator[] { FalseGenerator.Instance };
    }

    public void DisconnectInputGenerator() => ConnectInputWithOutput(FalseGenerator.Instance);

    public virtual void ConnectInputWithOutput(ISignalGenerator inputGenerator) =>
        InputGenerator = inputGenerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputGenerator));

    public abstract bool GetOutput();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var input  = Convert.ToInt32(InputGenerator.GetOutput());
        var output = Convert.ToInt32(GetOutput());

        return $"({input}) ---{GetType().Name}--> {output}";
    }

    void ILogicGate.DisconnectInputGenerator(int inputIndex)
    {
        if (inputIndex != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        DisconnectInputGenerator();
    }

    void ILogicGate.ConnectInputWithOutput(int inputIndex, ISignalGenerator inputGenerator)
    {
        if (inputIndex != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        ConnectInputWithOutput(inputGenerator);
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class NotGate : SingleInputGate
{
    public override bool GetOutput() => !InputGenerator.GetOutput();
}
```

```
public class DirectGate : SingleInputGate
{
    public sealed override bool GetOutput() => InputGenerator.GetOutput();
}
```

**Пользовательский вентиль:**

```
public sealed class UserGate : ILogicGate
{
    private readonly DirectGate[] _inputGates;

    public DirectGate OutputGate { get; } = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<DirectGate> InputGates { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<ISignalGenerator> ILogicGate.InputGenerators =>
        InputGates.Select(gate => gate.InputGenerator).ToArray();

    public UserGate(int inputsCount)
    {
        if (inputsCount < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputsCount));

        _inputGates = new DirectGate[inputsCount];
        InputGates  = new ReadOnlyCollection<DirectGate>(_inputGates);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputsCount; i++)
            _inputGates[i] = new();
    }

    public bool GetOutput() => OutputGate.GetOutput();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var inputs = string.Join(", ", InputGates.Select(gate => Convert.ToInt32(gate.GetOutput())));
        var output = Convert.ToInt32(GetOutput());

        return $"({inputs}) ---{GetType().Name}--> {output}";
    }

    void ILogicGate.DisconnectInputGenerator(int inputIndex)
    {
        if (inputIndex < 0 || inputIndex >= InputGates.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        InputGates[inputIndex].DisconnectInputGenerator();
    }

    void ILogicGate.ConnectInputWithOutput(int inputIndex, ISignalGenerator inputGenerator)
    {
        if (inputIndex < 0 || inputIndex >= InputGates.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputIndex));

        InputGates[inputIndex].ConnectInputWithOutput(inputGenerator);
    }
}
```

Тут сразу стоит пояснить, что весь сакральный смысл состоит в том, что каждый вход и выход пользовательского вентиля тоже является вентилем (DirectGate). Благодаря этому мы можем сделать связи как на картинке:

[image: Генератор, подключённый к NAND]
*Как видно из картинки, мы подключаем генератор (GEN) не напрямую к какому-то из внутренних вентелей (AND/NOT), а к входным вентилям (0/1), которые потом подключаются к внутренним (AND/NOT). Аналогично с выходом (R)*

**Пример из картинки в виде кода:**

```
var and = new AndGate(); // создали блок AND
var not = new NotGate(); // создали блок NOT
not.ConnectInputWithOutput(and); // подключили вход NOT к выходу AND

var nand = new UserGate(inputsCount: 2); // создали блок NAND с 2-мя входами
nand.OutputGate.ConnectInputWithOutput(not); // поключили выход NAND к выходу NOT

and.ConnectInputWithOutput(0, nand.InputGates[0]); // подключаем 0-й вход AND к 0-му входу NAND
and.ConnectInputWithOutput(1, nand.InputGates[1]); // подключаем 1-й вход AND к 1-му входу NAND

// подключаем входные сигналы NAND к генератору
nand.InputGates[0].ConnectInputWithOutput(TrueGenerator.Instance);
nand.InputGates[1].ConnectInputWithOutput(TrueGenerator.Instance);

Console.WriteLine(nand); // (1, 1) ---UserGate--> 0

// отключаем входные сигналы NAND от генератора
//nand.InputGates[0].DisconnectInputGenerator();
//nand.InputGates[1].DisconnectInputGenerator();

//Console.WriteLine(nand); // (0, 0) ---UserGate--> 1
```

Протестировать онлайн можно [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

---

**СОХРАНЕНИЕ**

Я не реализовывал сериализацию, но я думаю она вполне возможна с моим кодом. Я это вижу так:

1. Добавить каждому генератору/вентилю свойство `Guid` для хранения его уникального идентификатора в пределах схемы
2. Предположим, что мы работаем с System.Text.Json, тогда для классов `ILogicGate` нужно сделать конвертер, которые бы превращал все свои инпуты в массив `Guid` и наоборот. Для того чтобы работала десериализация, нужно будет изменить список `IReadOnlyList<ISignalGenerator> InputGenerators` на изменяемый. В идеале стоит сделать свой список, чтобы можно было безопасно изменять значения с проверкой на `null`.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит комплекснее, чем код Yaroslav'a. Не так сложно код не-юнити применить в юнити, так что обязательно попробую! Узнал для себя несколько функций языка, которые либо не знал, либо от редкого использования даже не вспомнил — ReadOnlyCollection, оператор ?? :)

Comment: я ещё раз подумал над задачей и вечером обновлю код на более удобный и логичный

Comment: Ваш код отлично работает! У меня только появился маленький вопросик: как мне сохранять собранный вентиль (экземпляр класса UserGate <- LogicGate)? Я пытался сделать это с помощью BinaryFormatter, но он жалуется, что не может сериализовать Func<>, как я понял. Можно как-то сохранять экземпляры UserGate в файл, чтобы использовать его в следующих запусках игры?

Comment: вот с новым кодом и эта проблема будет решена

Comment: Я три раза перечитал, чтобы понять, что проблема будет решена с новым кодом, а не с новым годом 

Comment: всё, обновил овет

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень понятный код. У меня все легко сериализовалось с помощью BinaryFormatter без каких-либо дополнительных действий (кроме, конечно, атрибута [Serializable]). Еще поэкспериментирую, ответ помечу

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class BoolChain
{
    public abstract bool GetOutValue ();
}
```

---

```
public class TrueChain : BoolChain
{
    public override bool GetOutValue () => true;

    public override string ToString () => "True";
}
```

---

```
public class NotChain : BoolChain
{
    public BoolChain In;

    public NotChain (BoolChain inChain = null)
    {
        In = inChain;
    }

    public override bool GetOutValue () => In.GetOutValue() == false;

    public override string ToString () => $"Not({In})";
}
```

---

```
public class AndChain : BoolChain
{
    public readonly BoolChain[] In;

    public AndChain (BoolChain[] inChain)
    {
        In = inChain;
    }

    public AndChain (int inCapacity = 2) : this(new BoolChain[inCapacity]) { }

    public override bool GetOutValue () 
    { 
        foreach (var chain in In)
            if (chain.GetOutValue() == false)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString () => $"And({string.Join(", ", In.Select(i => i.ToString()))})";
}
```

---

```
public class OrChain : BoolChain
{
    public readonly BoolChain[] In;

    public OrChain (BoolChain[] inChain)
    {
        In = inChain;
    }

    public OrChain (int inCapacity = 2) : this(new BoolChain[inCapacity]) { }

    public override bool GetOutValue ()
    {
        foreach (var chain in In)
            if (chain.GetOutValue())
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString () => $"Or({string.Join(", ", In.Select(i => i.ToString()))})";
}
```

Твой `BoolValve` должен содержать `BoolChain` в котором может быть что угодно. например тот-же `[False]` вентиль будет содержать `new NotChain(new TrueChain())` `"Not(True)"`. Добавь прототип для копирования целой цепочки `Clone()`, если добавить какой ни будь флаг `IsSelected`, можно ограничить копирование `CloneSelected()` и положить ее в новый `BoolValve`, что бы там ни было.

Comment: Черт возьми, три дня думал, а вы так быстро составили! Спасибо, вскоре смогу — протестирую.

Comment: Такой вопрос: в вашем коде, как я понимаю, предполагается, что любая цепочка chain в итоге сходится к классу TrueChain, так как это единственный класс, который возвращает значение, не опираясь на inputs. Мне же нужно, чтобы цепочка, ни к чему не сводилась (инпуты вентиля (на скрине это NAND) оставались пустыми), а уже сам игрок подсоединял входы этого вентиля к стартовым контактам (на первом скрине слева два красных). Например, со 2-го скрипта, блок NAND, как экземпляр класса BoolValve,  должен содержать переменную BoolChain (как вы и написали) примерно такую: ...

Comment: ... `BoolChain=new NotChain(new AndChain())`, но инпуты для AndChain НЕИЗВЕСТНЫ, пока блок NAND не будет размещен на поле и подключен к контактам слева на экране. **Вопрос**: как блоку NAND (экземпляру класса BoolValve) указать при его размещении на поле, к каким контактам слева он подключается и каковы их значения (включены/выключены)? Иначе говоря, как вентилю (имеющему свою сложную цепь) указать какие значения (true/false) служат входными? Ведь контакты активируются и деактивируются при клике мышкой.

Comment: Если вы ничего не поняли (это нормально, я формулировал вопрос минут 15), кратко: как часть своей игры, я просто хочу реализовать систему, как на видео с 4-й по 5-ю минуту. Ссылка в тексте вопроса

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос картинку, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Понятно, что поршень и логика, это две разные сущности, но поршню нужно иметь возможность спросить у логики. `out` всегда один и его можно спросить. `in` это понятно что массив, который может быть длинной как 0, так и 2+, но в моем примере метода для его запроса нет, но ясно что это всегда самый верхний уровень в цепочке (левый), достаточно лишь добавить `in`, возвращающий массив нужной длинны, в котором можно посмотреть сколько можно подключить и что там уже подключено или null`ы.

Answer (score 0):

пишу псевдокодом т.к. шарп уже забыл)

```
class Valve {
   private var type: ValveType
   var maxInputs: Int { type.MaxInputs() }
   var maxOutputs: Int { type.MaxOutputs() }
   var inputs: List<Point> = new List<Point>
   var outputs: List<Point> = new List<Point>
   
   func actionFunc() -> Void{
      switch type {
          case And: 
             andFunc();
             break;
          case Or:
             orFunc()
             break;
          default:
             defaultFunc()
      }
   }
}

enum ValveType {
    case And
    case Or
    case Xor
    case Not
    case Nand
}

extension ValveType {
    func MaxInputs() -> Int {
        switch self {
            case Nand:
               return 2;
               break;
            default: 
               return 2;
               break;
        }
    }

    func MaxOutputs() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

---

---

---

Ну или заделай себе фабрику которая будет выдавать вентили с необходимыми настройками

Comment: Угу, до этого я более или менее дотопал. Но здесь круг возможных вентилей четко ограничен перечислением ValveType. И это, как я понимаю, лишает меня возможности в рантайме создавать новые вентили. Если игрок из имеющихся вентилей соберет свою схему, например И(ИЛИ(А, НЕ(B)), С) и захочет объединить это в новый вентиль (как в видео) (с тремя входами и одним выходом), то как я в рантайме создам новый вентиль с кастомной функцией?

Comment: ну в конце я еще предложил фабрику которая будет собирать вентили с необходимой конфигурацией без возможности выбирать

Comment: Ну вот этого я и не понимаю. Не как сделать фабрику, а как создать вентиль с новой конфигурацией, составленной из конфигураций других, уже имеющихся, вентилей в рантайме.

Comment: ну ты делаешь фабрику которая генерит тебе вентили необходимых конфигураций. А так же имеешь таблицу соединений по которой можешь вычислить последовательность соединений. На практике фабрика будет иметь +- тот же самый код который я дал выше с той разницей что ты в ней сможешь или вручную задавать необходимую функцию или передавать туда свою функцию, а на выходе сможешь получать обьекты сразу необходимой конфигурации вместо задавания отдельно для каждого обьекта